# navbar collapse is not working as expected

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

the `li`s inside the `collapse` class are hidden on all the screen sizes.. I want them to hide only on a sm or md size. What 's the problem? I have bootstrap 4.3.1 included.

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-nav navbar-default">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">Hotel Corona</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a href="/">Log In</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/">Sign Up</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/">Log Out</a></li>
                            </ul>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
```

Comment: You're using Bootstrap 3 Navbar markup.. use the correct [Navbar markup for Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Bootstrap 4 - Hiding elements](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/#hiding-elements). Basically you can set .d-sm-none .d-md-block for example to only hide it at small screen sizes, but show on md.

Small addition: You can also set this as a navbar class directly, read [Navbar - How it works](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#how-it-works)  (Navbars require a wrapping .navbar with .navbar-expand{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl} for responsive collapsing and color scheme classes.) for this

Comment: yeah but I kinda want to do it using the collapse class.. because I want to know why it doesn't work